# Spring JPA override mechanism when entites have the same name

Tags: spring, jpa, duplicates, overriding, entity

Is there any possibility to have duplicate entities with the same name? And just one of them gets registered if a specific condition is met?

The reason is the following:
Based on some database configuration a customer specific implementation of the basicentity should be used.

Maybe there is a better solution for this problem.

E.G.

```
@Entity(name="basicentity")
public class IntegrationBasicResource extends BaseAuditEntity {

@Entity(name="basicentity")
public class CustomerIntegrationBasicResource extends BaseAuditEntity {
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by splitting the entities in different packages and using a combination between `@EntityScan` and `@ConditionalOnProperty` on different `@Configuration` classes.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(value="client.type", havingValue="a")
@EntityScan("com.test.database.client.a")    
public class EntityConfigClientTypeA {
  ...
}
```

There are many types of `@ConditionalOn...` annotations if setting via properties does not fit your use case.